# Why does CSS box-shadow produce shadow's in unwanted positions?

Tags: css

Why does:

```
div { -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0 20px #c1c1c1; }
```

put a shadow underneath the div when it's clearly set to 0?

Comment: What do you mean 'underneath'? What position do you intend for the box shadow to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not putting the shadow "underneath" the box, it's just bluring to the point that it's visible underneath. The parameters are:

`-webkit-box-shadow: (Horizontal) (Vertical) (Blur) (Color);`

http://jsfiddle.net/ngjpr/

Comment: That's what I thought. Was hoping there was another way of doing it without images so the shadow would just be either horizontal or vertical and not have the blur overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
div { -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0 20px #c1c1c1; }
```

Sets the `-webkit-box-shadow` with an offset of `5px` (horizontal) and `0` (vertical) with a blur radius of `20px` of colour `#c1c1c1`.

This means that the shadow *isn't* set to 0, it's just moved `0` vertically. If you want to have no shadow, either set the blur radius (`20px`) to `0` or remove the `-webkit-box-shadow` property.

Comment: ...or wrap a bounding div with `overflow: none` to clip the unwanted shadow (although this will cause some abrupt edges to the shadow).